# Каков срок хранения и службы неиспользовавшегося жесткого диска?

Tags: железо, hdd, диск

Здравствуйте. 
Нашел жесткий диск на 1 террабайт. Диск включался 19 раз, общее время работы - 9 дней, тесты проходит, health - ok. Смущает дата выпуска - 12.2009. Слышал, что средний срок службы винта около 10 лет, но это для работающих. Каков срок хранения для почти нового? Можно ли ставить его в систему и рассчитывать еще на 10 лет, или год для него это максимум?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полагаю, что как и у всех не пищевых продуктов срок будет неограничен.
По факту, же здесь играют роль условия хранения.

Разумно полагать, что в нём есть смарт и он подскажет, когда возможны проблемы.
В остальном, пользуйтесь и радуйтесь находке :)

P.S.: как правильно отметил комрад ниже, не лишним будет полагаться и на тесты Viktoria и MHDD, они детально покажут пригодность любого винта.

Comment: Не хочу писать отдельный ответ. Допиши про `Victoria` и `MHDD`.

Answer (score 0):

Мы в своем оборудовании поставляли винты в холодном резерве. После выхода из строя основного винта, переключались на резервный. 70% таких подключенных винтов работало год-два и здыхало.

Правда два но

1. Это было более 10 лет назад.
2. Оборудование (с резервным винтом) устанавливалось на крышах и чердачных помещениях. Т.е. климатические условия были далеко не офисными